# How do I connect back to remote bitbucket repository after removing it?

Tags: git

I removed the link to my bit bucket repository and cannot link back to it. I accidentally did this:

```
git remote rm origin
```

following this, I am trying to link back to my remote repository.

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myproject.git
```

it got added.

Following that, if I try

```
git push origin master
```

I get the this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org:myaccount: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

what should I do to be able to link back to my remote repository?

Answer (score 4):

Url format might be wrong.

The URL you use to access a repository depends on the connection protocol (HTTPS or SSH) and the DVCS program. The following shows the URL format for each case Bitbucket supports:

**SSH URL format**

*Mercurial*

```
ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/<reponame>/
```

*Git*

`git@bitbucket.org:<accountname>/<reponame>.git`
or

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/<reponame>.git
```

**HTTPS URL format**

*Mercurial*

```
https://accountname@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/<reponame>
```

*Git*

```
https://<accountname>@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/<reponame>.git
```

Comment: It's strange, in Xcode I have been using `ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<accountname>/<reponame>.git` (note this one does not exactly match any of the formats you listed due to the colon instead of a slash) and that seems to work for pushing, but when I pull, I have to correct it to `ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/<reponame>.git` like you mentioned.

Comment: Switching the `:` to a `/` in the Git SSH URL solved this for me. The colon version worked for a while (set that way in my original clone), but just recently it started failing. Must be something funky going on over at Bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a better way, but if all else fails you can just remove your local repository (save any recently changed files to some temporary folder), and clone it again from BitBucket.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error is given if you have an issue with your network connection. I happened to have. Maybe it helps somebody.